# KDB:Can kdb solve the topn problem without sorting

Tags: sorting, select, tabs, kdb

Suppose I have a large table(orders), and I want to select the top 10 records in a certain column (such as sales). If you sort first and then fetch the top 10 records, the efficiency will be very low. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
select[10] from `sales xasc orders
```

This is a very inefficient way, is there a more efficient solution, thank you for the help?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use [`rank`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/rank/) to achieve this.

The function `rank` returns the index of where each item would occur in a sorted list. That can then be used to find all indices under 10 in your case, which corresponds to the top 10 records.

```
/ example orders table
orders:([]sales:30?til 100)

q)select from orders where 10>rank sales
sales
-----
8
19
12
11
1
0
4
10
18
17
```

Getting the bottom 10 records requires using `iasc idesc`.

```
q)select from orders where 10>iasc idesc sales
sales
-----
94
92
69
64
96
74
81
99
70
91
```

Comment: In this way, it is still sorted in essence, but instead of returning the sorted table, it returns the sorted index, because `(asc L)~L iasc L` is actually sorts L.We can think of top 10 as an aggregation operation, like max, min, etc., but it is convenient to maintain a list of length 10. This kind of operation will be much more efficient, right?

Answer (score 1):

`select` does have built-in sorting which is about as efficient as your going to get in an unsorted table:

```
q)N:10000000
q)orders:([]sales:N?N;px:N?1.0)
q)select[10;>sales]from orders
sales   px
------------------
9999999 0.06215429
9999999 0.4136333
9999998 0.5204079
9999998 0.7360435
9999997 0.8785856
9999997 0.2171333
9999995 0.4756799
9999994 0.6722243
9999993 0.09643629
9999992 0.5985121
q)
```

However, whatever way you look at it - you cant get top 10 without a sort/rank. The only way you could make it *significantly* faster is to pre-treat the data: pre-sort, use attributes, pre-calc the rank on each update etc

Comment: top 10 can theoretically maintain a list with a length of 10. When traversing the data, compare it with the maximum value in this list to ensure that the 10 numbers in the list are always the largest 10. In fact, max is also implemented in this way, but it is Just compare a value. In this way, a large sort can be avoided, but kdb does not have this method?

Comment: Let's say you want to find n largest elements of an array of size N. On average you'd need O(N log N) operations to sort the array first with "sort first and take top n" approach or, alternatively, you can maintain a min-priority queue of size n, traverse the array and insert an element if it is greater than the least element of the queue O(log n) and thus reduce the complexity down to O(N log n). If you did this in pure q, however, you wouldn't get any performance benefit because you'd have to write loops almost certainly. So it's either sort-first or a C extension if you *absolutely* need it

Answer (score 0):

Thomas and Terry's answers cover what you should do to get topN rows from a table for a given column.

On your question of trying to craft a smarter function:

4 different functions to grab 10 ten items from a list:

```
top10Over:{{$[10>count x;desc x,y;$[y>=last x;10#desc x,y;x]]} over (),x}
top10Rank:{desc x where (count[x]-11)<rank x}
top10Idesc:{x 10#idesc x}
top10Desc:{10#desc x}
```

A list to test on:

```
list:1000000?100.0
```

Confirm all return the same answer:

```
q)1~count distinct `top10Over`top10Rank`top10Idesc`top`10Desc@\:list
1b
```

Time them all:

```
q)\ts top10Over list
468 1120
q)\ts top10Rank list
141 25166080
q)\ts top10Idesc list
72 33554656
q)\ts top10Desc list
67 33554656
```

`over` is used as an iterator to go through the list keeping a cache of the top 10 items. `over` can be very useful/powerful but for this example is "noisy", performing many small tasks. Is uses very little memory but is slow. The inbuilt `idesc` and other out of box operators are very well optimised and often are hard to beat.
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/over/#over-scan

Naturally timing will change with size and datatype of the list.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I learned a lot.